# is it possible to store the PrimeFaces exported data programmatically?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I need to store the exported data into some file as string or as excel format and I want to send that file using email.

my current export statement is

```
 <p:dataExporter  type="xls" target="tableWbTicketold" fileName="TicketOldReport" />
```

Comment: yes its working fine..the problem is i want to store the exported data into somewhere else

Comment: By using dataExporter, you are able to Download the file, and as you said, it's already working. Where do you want to store that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two alternatives:

1. use postProcessor: `<p:dataExporter type="xls" target="tbl" fileName="cars" postProcessor="#{tableBean.postProcessXLS}"/>`.
   you can email the WorkBook inside `tableBean.postProcessXLS`, but this will not prevent the normal flow (file download dialog)
2. write your own `DataExporter` custom component extending PF classes and overriding: `DataExporter.processAction`, `ExcelExporter.export`

---

**UPDATE**

this way:

```
public void postProcessXLS(Object document)
{
    try
    {
        Workbook wb = (Workbook) document;

        File file = File.createTempFile("exporter-", ".xls");

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        wb.write(out); // or write in mail body
        out.close();

        // do what you need with file

        file.delete();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: but how can i get the exported file means the xls file in postProcessXLS method.